# gpio input read 0, but voltage is 3V3

Tags: power, pins

I'm using GPIO api and configure it as input pull down. It reads value 0. However, when I use power meter, and connect this gpio and ground, it shows 3.3V. Is it normal or maybe some other peripheral module actually pull this gpio high? To reduce power consumption, should I connect this gpio to 3V3 and configure it as input pull high? Thanks.

Comment: What is your `vref` tied to?

Comment: How have you configured the pin as pull-down? Did you add an external resistor?

Comment: Please show your wiring and your code. Your description is not clear, on Arduino MCU, there is no notion of "input pulldown", it is either "input" (high impedence) or "input pullup".